# pfgplottable borders missing

Tags: pgfplotstable

I try to place borders on the left and right of my pgfplottable.

```
\begin{table}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 % col sep=comma,              %
 every head row/.style={
  before row={
    \hline
       & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Unit [d]}\\
  },
  after row=\hline
},
% header=false,
every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
every even row/.style={
before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
col sep=comma,
string type,
columns/0/.style={column name={Task}, column type={|l}},
columns/1/.style={column name={A}, column type={|l}},
columns/2/.style={column name={B}, column type={|l}},
columns/3/.style={column name={C}, column type={|l|}},
]{
Task, A, B, C
Bread, 100, 50, 30
}
\caption{Tasks}
\end{table}
```

I'd think, that the column types specify to place a border on the outside of the border. But [image: this] is what I get.

Any ideas, why the borders are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible solution where column style 0,1,2,3 are changed to t,a,b,c and the codes for column styles are simplified. Also the contents of the first row should be the column style since their names are defined in the style definitions. Current column type is `l` for left, if center is preferred use `c` instead.

To show `caption` within `table` environment, enable related commands and use `article` class.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
%\begin{table}
%\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 col sep=comma,              %
% row sep=\\,
 every head row/.style={
  before row={
    \hline
       & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Unit [d]} \\
  },
  after row=\hline
},
% header=false,
every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
every even row/.style={
before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
col sep=comma, string type,
columns/t/.style={column type=|l,column name=Task},
columns/a/.style={column type=l,column name=A},
columns/b/.style={column name=B, column type=l},
columns/c/.style={column name=C, column type=l|},
]{
t, a, b, c
Bread, 100, 50, 30
}
%\caption{Tasks}
%\end{table}

\end{document}
```